# why WPF context menu of a user control only show up particular places within the user control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I m working on a noteBook project and i noticed one annoying behavior of context menu.

I have a user control in which i defined three textblocks. here is the code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NoteBookPractice.View.Controls.NoteControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NoteBookPractice.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="75" d:DesignWidth="400">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
               Margin="2"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="13"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Foreground="White"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreatedAt}"
               Margin="2"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="10"
               FontWeight="Light"
               Foreground="White"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdatedAt}"
               Margin="2"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="10"
               FontWeight="Light"
               Foreground="White"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and here is the code in my window to use this user control:

```
<ListView DockPanel.Dock="Left"
              Background="DarkCyan"
              Width="150"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedNote}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <uc:NoteControl Note="{Binding}">
                    <uc:NoteControl.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Rename"
                                  Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=RenameNoteCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                                  Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=DeleteNoteCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                    </uc:NoteControl.ContextMenu>
                </uc:NoteControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

everything works great. But i noticed the context menu will note show when the user clicks places other than the text inside the user control.. see image below:

[image: Clicking on void areas doesn't show context menu]

[image: only clicking on text does show it]

This is annoying because i thought the binding was not working. But then i clicked another place and it showed up. I guess a user will also be confused

is there any way i can make the context menu to show up wherever the user clicked on the note user control?

Comment: Add a (transparent) background color to your NoteControl?

Comment: Adding a background doesn't help. Setting horizontal alignment to stretch doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search.. i found a way to do this. Adding this code to the listview body

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

applying horizontalContentAlignment to user control directly or any of its parents seemed to be not working.